# Coming back to fragment from other activity?

Tags: android, fragment

I have 3 activities A1,A2, and A3.

First activity(A1) has 3 fragments(fA,fB and fC) in it.From fragment 
"fB" I am going to my A2 activity and from A2 I am going to A3 .

Now from A3 activity, I want to come back to fragment fB on button press.
I can come back to A1 ,but not to fb.Is it possible to come back to fb ?If yes then how ?

```
              public void onClick(View v) {

               Intent intent = new Intent(A3.this,  A1.class);
             // Intent intent = new Intent(A3.this,  fB.class);
              startActivity(intent);
```

Error
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class 
It is a fragment so I can't declare it in manifests.

Comment: Fragments are within the activities. Your fragment B is within the Activity A. You should go back to your Activity A and it will be there. I think your problem is in smth else.

Comment: How you finishing the two activity which you are opening from fragment

Comment: You have to do nothing. It should remain in fB if you press the back button or `finish` the activities. Unless you put any flags like CLEAR_TOP in manifest

Comment: Yes, I am saying that I am able to go back to the fragment activity but not to a particular fragment.So it is not possible to go back to a particular fragment from another activity? @AlexanderKulyakhtin

Comment: Yes on back press I am able to come to fb fragment from A3activity but I have to press it 2 time@Clairvoyant

Comment: I am not finishing the fragment f2,so how can I come back to f2 on a single back press or button press.@ReazMurshed

Comment: Save the Activity2 instance at the Activity3. Upon button press at the Activity3, call finish from both the activities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass a boolean through Intent.

```
intent.putExtra("isFromActivity3", true);
```

Then get the boolean value at the Activity onCreate(),

```
getIntent().getBooleanExtra("isFromActivity3", false);
```

If the boolean value is true, then add the fragmentB to the Activity1.

Update :

I think, the following code will suffice,

from Activity3,

```
this.finish();
activity2.finish();
```

this will take you to the FragmentB in the Activity1.

Comment: Can u clarify little bit @Dinesh Bob

Comment: Fragment cannot exist without a Activity. So to come back to FragmentB from Activity3, you have to come back to Activity1 and add the FragmentB to the Activity1.

Comment: I updated the answer. Save the Activity2 instance in the Activity3. Then call finish() from the Activity3 and Activity2. If you create new Intent to go to FragmentB, this will create a new FragmentB, not take you back to the same FragmentB.

Comment: Doing this it is working but it gives a message that app has stopped and on pressing ok button it starts working @Dinesh Bob

Comment: It is not working. The message "app has stopped" means there is some runtime error in the app and the app is crashed. Can you post the error log?

Comment: Hi @Dinesh Bob thanks, I resolved It. this.finish and activity2.finish() shows compilation error .So I just use finish() for both A2 and A3 activity so now on back press it is going to that fB fragment and on custom  button press I use the activity class name and it is redirecting me to fragment fB.   Button retake = (Button) findViewById(R.id.retakebtn);

        retake.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            Override
            public void onClick(View v) { Intent intent = new Intent(this,A1.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();